# Links' height won't fit in grid display

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to fit a RSS flux in a grid displayed div, but somehow, they won't fit perfectly.

[My Website](https://tvo35400.com)

Here is my CSS code

```
#rss-5 ul {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(45%, 1fr));
grid-gap: 10px 10px;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

#rss-5 ul li {
padding: 0;
border-bottom: none;
}

#rss-5 ul li a.rsswidget {
display:inline-block;
width:90%;
height:90%;
color: #454545;
transition: 0.5s;
padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 3px solid #4ED4B5;
font-family: 'Josefin sans';
font-size: 18px;
}
```

In advance, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like the black box over the image? You need to place a position of absolute on the wrap which basically says don't pay attention to the other elements on the page and try to avoid them. You then need to place a position relative on its parent which is the slides which says the absolutely positioned element is only relative to its parent.

```
.slides{
    position: relative;
}
.caption-wrap {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[screenshot for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghfhH.png)